# remove inner <mark> tags using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tags, javascript-objects

I have a paragraph where some words are highlighted using `<mark>` tag.
But when the document is ready, some of the words contains `<mark>`tag inside another `<mark>` tag.
i.e `<mark><mark>MyWord</mark></mark>`

Here is the code
`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('mark').each(function () {
if ($(this).next().is('mark')) {
   $(this).next().remove();
}
});
});
</script>`
```

How will i delete extra mark tags so that MyWord contain single mark tag.i.e
`<mark>MyWord</mark>`

Comment: "*...when the document is ready, some of the words contains `<mark>` tag inside another `<mark>`...*" - how are these nested `<mark>` elements being generated? This can - easily - be corrected client side with JavaScript, but it seems a better idea to prevent the problem if at all possible.

Comment: not all the words have nested `<mark>` tags.. words are highlighted based upon two different sources. So when the document becomes ready two or three words contain nested tags.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be easier to use `display: contents` CSS on the mark tags, so that although they're still in the page, the browser ignores them.

Comment: still displaying nested tags. when i have inspected code. mark tag is there.

Comment: Yes, they will still be there, but the point is that they won't affect what the page looks like.

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work when I tried pure jQuery, so I resorted to DOM APIs.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    let marks = document.querySelectorAll('mark');
    for (let i = 0; i < marks.length; ++i) {
      let mark = marks[i];
      mark.after(...mark.childNodes);
      mark.remove();
    }
});
```

For each mark, I take its contents and place them beside the mark and then delete the now empty mark. This works even with nested marks.

I referenced the API for Nodes and Elements (an Element is a type of Node):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

A mark is always an Element as it's a tag. Contents such as a mark's text is just a Node, not a tag/Element. As such, I made sure to use `.childNodes` from the Node API so that the text would also be moved. Rather than manually move each node one-by-one, I noticed that `.after` from the Element API accepts multiple Nodes, but I can't pass the `NodeList` directly, so I need to use the JavaScript spread operator to unpack it.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**